# Searching for range overlaps in Ruby hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

Say you have the following Ruby hash,

```
hash = {:a => [[1, 100..300],
               [2, 200..300]],
        :b => [[1, 100..300], 
               [2, 301..400]]
       }
```

and the following functions,

```
def overlaps?(range, range2)
  range.include?(range2.begin) || range2.include?(range.begin)
end

def any_overlaps?(ranges)
  # This calls to_proc on the symbol object; it's syntactically equivalent to 
  # ranges.sort_by {|r| r.begin} 
  ranges.sort_by(&:begin).each_cons(2).any? do |r1, r2|
    overlaps?(r1, r2)
  end
end
```

and it's your desire to, for each key in `hash`, test whether any range overlaps with any other.  In `hash` above, I would expect `hash[:a`] to make me mad and `hash[:b]` to not.

How is this best implemented syntactically?

Comment: I like your solution and have nothing to add. Except of use some analogical methods it `overlaps?`, if wish to make code more compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hash.each{|k, v| puts "#{k} #{any_overlaps?( v.map( &:last )) ? 'overlaps' : 'is ok'}."}
```

output:

```
a overlaps.
b is ok.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to write `any_overlaps`:

```
def any_overlaps?(ranges)
  (a = ranges.map { |r| [r.first, r.last] }.sort_by(&:first).flatten) != a.sort 
end

any_overlaps? [(51..60),(11..20),(18..30),(0..10),(31..40)] # => true
any_overlaps? [(51..60),(11..20),(21..30),(0..10),(31..40)] # => false
```